# Sparse O(1) array with indices being consecutive products

Tags: c++, algorithm, sparse-array

I'd like to pre-calculate an array of values of some unary function `f`.

I know that I'll only need the values for `f(x)` where `x` is of the form of `a*b`, where both `a` and `b` are integers in range `0..N`.

The obvious time-optimized choice is just to make an array of size `N*N` and just pre-calculate just the elements which I'm going to read later. For `f(a*b)`, I'd just check and set `tab[a*b]`. This is the fastest method possible - however, this is going to take a lot of space as there are lots of indices in this array (starting with `N+1`) which will never by touched.

Another solution is to make a simple tree map... but this slows down the lookup itself *very* heavily by introducing lots of branches. No.

I wonder - is there any solution to make such an array less sparse and smaller, but still quick branchless O(1) in lookup?

**edit**

I can hear lots of comments about a hash map... I'll proceed to benchmark how one behaves *(I expect a significant performance drop over normal lookup due to branching; less than in trees, but still... let's see if I'm right!)*.

I'd like to emphasize: I'd mostly appreciate an **analytical** solution which would use some clever way (?) to take advantage of the fact that only "product-like" indices are taken. I feel that this fact might be exploited to get a way better result that an average generic hash map function, but I'm out of ideas myself.

**edit**

Following your advice, I've tried `std::unordered_map` from gcc 4.5. This was a tad slower than the simple array lookup, but indeed much faster than the tree-based `std::map` - ultimately I'm OK with this solution. I understand now why it's not possible to do what I originally intended to; thanks for the explanations!

**I'm just unsure whether the hash-map actually saves any memory!** :) As @Keith Randall has described, I cannot get the memory footprint lower than `N*N/4`, and the triangular matrix approach described by @Sjoerd gives me `N*N/2`. I think that it's entirely possible for the hash map to use more than `N*N/2` space if the element size is small (depends on the container overhead) - which would make the fastest approach also the most memory-effective! I'll try to check that.

I wish I could accept 2 answers...

Comment: Can you change `f` to be `f(a, b)`?

Comment: Of course... even a wrapper can do that. The result depends only on the product.

Comment: Well, it wasn't clear if you actually knew `a` and `b` at the time of the call or whether you just had `x`.

Comment: If you find a fast way to skip unused entries, it could be turned into a fast way to tell whether a number is prime. As the latter is considered a hard problem, I doubt you'll get an good analytical solution for your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a lot of structure to take advantage of here.  If you're asking if there is a way to arrange to arrange the table such that you can avoid storage for entries that can't happen (because they have a prime factor larger than N), you can't save much.  There is a [theory of smooth numbers](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_number) which states that the density of N-smooth numbers near N^2 is ~2^-2.  So, absolute best case, you can reduce the (maximum) storage requirement by at most a factor of 4.

I think you're better off taking advantage of symmetry and then using a hash table if you expect most arguments to never occur.

Answer (score 5):

Start with looking at it as a two-dimensional array: `tab[a][b]`. This still requires N*N size.

Each entry will be used, but there will be duplication: `f(a,b) = f(b,a)`. So only a triangular matrix is required (at the cost of one branch for a>b vs a<b).

```
if (a < b) return tab[b*(b+1) + a]; // assuming 0 <= a < b < N
else return tab[a*(a+1) + b];       // assuming 0 <= b <= a < N
```

Or

```
if (a < b) return tab[b*(b-1) + a]; // assuming 1 <= a < b <= N
else return tab[a*(a-1) + b];       // assuming 1 <= b <= a <= N
```

EDIT: the memory used by a triangular matrix is (N+1)*N/2, about half the size of a square matrix. Still quadratic, though :(

EDIT2: Note that er is still duplication in the matrix: e.g. `f(3, 2) = f(6, 1)`. I don't think this can be eliminated without introducing lots of branches and loops, but that's just a gut feeling.

Comment: this assumes that f(a,b) does indeed equal f(b,a)

Comment: @Will As the question states that only the product of a and b is used in the calculation, I assumed that was the case.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply hash the A and B combo and put the results in a map? And do it lazily so you just get the ones you want?

```
public Result f(Type1 a, Type2 b) {
    TypePair key = new TypePair(a, b);
    Result res = map.get(key);
    if (res == null) {
        res = reallyCalculate(a, b);
        map.put(key, res);
    }
    return res;
}
```

Basic memoization.

Comment: This looks an awful lot like Not C++.

Comment: Due to the distribution of `(a,b)`, there will be an awful lots of collisions. And each collision is another branch. Not to mention the memomry overhead for the collision lists. For small N, a simple N*N array will require less memory and be faster. Maybe the actual N will be in that range?

Comment: Depends on the hash function and the size of the underlying array. If the array is large enough and the hash is good, there is no benefit to using an n x n array - especially if it is sparse.

Comment: @Andrei You rely on "if [...] the hash is good." That's a big assumption.

Comment: Well, the programmer has control over the hash function, so it's up to them.

Answer (score 0):

[Hash tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) provide a good balance between lookup speed and memory overhead. The C++ standard library does not provide a hash table, although it is sometimes available as a non-standard extension. See the [SGI hash_map](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/hash_map.html) for example.

The Poco C++ library also has a HashTable and HashMap classes, see the [documentation](http://pocoproject.org/docs/).